# During int to char conversion where int is to large to be stored in char, what will be the values that will be stored in char if int is too large?

Tags: c++

```
   double d=0;
   while(cin>>d){
       int i=d;    
       char c=i;   
       int i2=c;  
       cout<<"d=="<<d
           <<"i=="<<i
           <<"i2=="<<i2
           <<" char("<<c<<")\n";
}
```

I am reading Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ 2nd Edition. I am at Safe and Unsafe Conversions topic. The code given is an exercise, when ran, I input 1000, then it output

```
d==1000i==1000i2==-24 char(Φ)
```

i would like to know what the machine do when the int is too large for char to store like that 1000 became -24.

Comment: 1024 is a multiple of 256, which is 2^8, and a char is often 8 bits. 1000 is 24 less, so -24 == 1000 modulo 256.

Comment: For regular chars the value of the char is 1024%127 and for unsigned char it is 1024%256. This is considered bad practice though

Comment: @Jake For non-`unsigned char`s, there is no well-defined value; it's implementation defined at best. If you saw the result `1024%127`, that's a detail of your implementation.

Comment: @underscore_d my apologies it is % 128

Comment: @Jake Freeman, may you please elaborate what bad practice are you talking about, and why?

Comment: When you assign a value outside the range of a char you are overflowing the buffer. The warning my compiler gives is `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion `

Comment: @JakeFreeman I may be wrong but right now am not aware of any case in which signed integer overflow has a well-defined result, being at best left up to the implementation to choose whether or not there's a predictable result.

Comment: @underscore_d I did a test on the C9 compiler and the result was x%128. Regardless of how large or small x.

Comment: @JakeFreeman Read my comments again. What one implementation does is supremely uninteresting IMHO. That is: just because your implementation returns a particular result does not mean that the Standard requires it to, or that writing code that relies on that result is not going to break horribly when compiled on a different system.

Answer (score 5):

> During int to char conversion where int is to large to be stored in char, what will be the values that will be stored in char

It depends.

In particular, it depends on whether `char` type is signed or unsigned. Whether `char` is signed, is implementation defined.

If `char` is unsigned, then the resulting value is the smallest unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in `char`.

If `char` is signed, then the resulting value is implementation defined. Which means that the value can be any value representable by `char`. In *practice*, on systems that represent negative numbers as two's complement (and most processors do use two's complement), it is typical that the same modulo relation applies to signed types as well. But this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard.

From this, we can deduce that `char` is signed on your system, because -24 is not representable by an unsigned type. -24 is indeed congruent with 1000 modulo 2<sup>8</sup>

---

Standard reference: [[conv.integral]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral)

> 2 If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).
>   [ Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation).
>   — end note]
>
> 3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Comment: One could, additionally, add a quote from the standard (sections 7.8.2-7.8.3 regarding integer conversions).

Comment: @Kimley • if you find the vagueness of the answer unsatisfying, it is because C and C++ are languages which try to eke out all the possible performance of the platform by NOT imposing constraints that would be suboptimal on some platforms.  That is one of the reasons that contribute to C and C++ learning curve, and makes writing truly portable C/C++ code a little more challenging.